# jquery ajax fetch data in array cakephp

Tags: ajax, jquery, cakephp

I am new to jquery ajax. I am working in cakephp and I have following to do:
I have 7 links: `sun, mon, tue, wed, ...`

Now onclick of each link I wish to store the text of that link into an array which I can access in controller. I wish to do this using jquery ajax.

Following is my code which is not working (jquery ajax test code):

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->link('sun', 
    array('onclick' => 'callAjax();'), 
    array('class' => 'dayss'));
?>
<script>
function callAjax() {

        $.ajax({ 
            url: "rideoffers/ride_offer",
            type: "POST",
            success: function() {
            console.log("hi");
            },
            error: function() {
            console.log("error");
            }
        });
return true;
}
</script>
```

The above code doesnt print hi or error. Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve it?

**edited: Dipesh parmar**

```
    <pre>CakeRequest Object
(
    [params] => Array
        (
            [plugin] => 
            [controller] => Rideoffers
            [action] => ride_array
            [named] => Array
                (
                )

            [pass] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [data] => Array
        (
        )

    [query] => Array
        (
        )

    [url] => Rideoffers/ride_array
    [base] => /carpooling
    [webroot] => /carpooling/
    [here] => /carpooling/Rideoffers/ride_array
    [_detectors:protected] => Array
        (
            [get] => Array
                (
                    [env] => REQUEST_METHOD
                    [value] => GET
                )

            [post] => Array
                (
                    [env] => REQUEST_METHOD
                    [value] => POST
                )

            [put] => Array
                (
                    [env] => REQUEST_METHOD
                    [value] => PUT
                )

            [delete] => Array
                (
                    [env] => REQUEST_METHOD
                    [value] => DELETE
                )

            [head] => Array
                (
                    [env] => REQUEST_METHOD
                    [value] => HEAD
                )

            [options] => Array
                (
                    [env] => REQUEST_METHOD
                    [value] => OPTIONS
                )

            [ssl] => Array
                (
                    [env] => HTTPS
                    [value] => 1
                )

            [ajax] => Array
                (
                    [env] => HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH
                    [value] => XMLHttpRequest
                )

            [flash] => Array
                (
                    [env] => HTTP_USER_AGENT
                    [pattern] => /^(Shockwave|Adobe) Flash/
                )

            [mobile] => Array
                (
                    [env] => HTTP_USER_AGENT
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Android
                            [1] => AvantGo
                            [2] => BlackBerry
                            [3] => DoCoMo
                            [4] => Fennec
                            [5] => iPod
                            [6] => iPhone
                            [7] => iPad
                            [8] => J2ME
                            [9] => MIDP
                            [10] => NetFront
                            [11] => Nokia
                            [12] => Opera Mini
                            [13] => Opera Mobi
                            [14] => PalmOS
                            [15] => PalmSource
                            [16] => portalmmm
                            [17] => Plucker
                            [18] => ReqwirelessWeb
                            [19] => SonyEricsson
                            [20] => Symbian
                            [21] => UP\.Browser
                            [22] => webOS
                            [23] => Windows CE
                            [24] => Windows Phone OS
                            [25] => Xiino
                        )

                )

            [requested] => Array
                (
                    [param] => requested
                    [value] => 1
                )

        )

    [_input:protected] => 
)
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your `url` parameter is correct:

```
url: "rideoffers/ride_offer"
```

Is it?  Can you replicate the request not using ajax and get the desired results (e.g. have your ajax target url accept the same request using GET and test it's output)?

If not, maybe your console is messed up? Try dumping your debug lines using alert instead of console:

e.g.

```
alert("hi")
```

Comment: i tried to alert(), still it does nothing and i guess i ll hv to use ajax to meet my requirement

Comment: can you confirm your javascript doens't have any errors?  use a browser js validation plugin to test that

Comment: the problem was with echo, if i write <a href> then the ajax call is done, but now where do i declare the array in cakephp which i can use in controller and to which i can assign data in ajax call?

Comment: probably second argument to html link cakephp helper is reserved for specify url and he assiging onclick event that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `return false;` in the `onclick` event and try to return the ajax itself.

```
<?php
   echo $this->Html->link('sun',  
   array('class' => 'dayss'));
?>
<script>
 $(function(){
   $('.dayss').on('click', callAjax);
 });

 function callAjax() {
    return $.ajax({ 
        url: "rideoffers/ride_offer",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
        console.log("hi");
        console.log(data);
        },
        error: function() {
        console.log("error");
        }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: the problem was with echo, if i write <a href> then the ajax call is done, but now where do i declare the array in cakephp which i can use in controller and to which i can assign data in ajax call?

Comment: probably second argument to html link cakephp helper is reserved for specify url and he assiging onclick event that is the issue.

Comment: thanks but  where do i declare the array in cakephp which i can use in controller and to which i can assign data in ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

Code Must be as below.

```
echo $this->Html->link('sun', array(),array('onclick' => 'callAjax();','class' => 'dayss'));
```

Second argument to `Html->link` is for `href` and you assigning `onclick` event inside it.

**Response to Comment**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callAjax()
{
    var textString = $(this).text();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "rideoffers/ride_offer",
        type: "POST",
        data : textString,
        success: function()
        {
            console.log("hi");
        },
        error: function()
        {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

    function ride_offer()
    {
        //to test data is passed as needed.
        pr($this->params);
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: thanks but where do i declare the array in cakephp which i can use in controller and to which i can assign data in ajax call?

Comment: i can't get it...what array and what to pass..?? you can pass data in ajax call by defining data : in $.ajax.

Comment: well please look at my question, it says there are 7 links and on click of each link i want to retrieve the text of the link in an array. Now this array is in the view and i wish to access this array data in my controller also. So how do i do this i mean how do use an array in view?

Comment: you mean on every link click you want to get text of that link.?

Comment: yes i want to get appended string on each link click, eg. click sun- string is: sun, then click mon- string is sun, mon, ...n so on

Comment: thanks but when i tried your solution i got the following output: check my edited post above.

Comment: no it didnt, i got the output as shown in edited post, the named param returns nothing

Comment: i got it when i wrote $this->request->input() instead of $this->params in controller. but the problem is that i get the data in <pre> tag. How do i remove <pre> tag?

Comment: oh okay but i still get lots of white spaces and line breaks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24367/discussion-between-dipesh-parmar-and-z22)